# estpost with factor variable notation

Tags: stata

I want to make a table that displays all levels of my variables. For that I use the ibn notation. However, it seems that factor variable notation is not compatible with estpost and esttab. Is there a way to export summary statistics with factor variable notation to excel/word?

```
estpost sum ibn.male ibn.edu_lvl ibn.age_cat
```

Error: factor variables and time series operators not allowed.

All of my variables are not categorical on their own, but encoded, so I think the issue is the ibn prefix. Is it possible to have it somehow exported to excel?

UPD.: `xi, noomit: estpost sum i.varname`  displayed summary statistics by levels, however it displayed the values of variables, e.g. (male == 1, male ==0) instead of labels of values (male, female)

Answer (score 3):

`estpost summarize` expects a varlist as an input (see `help estpost`), and `ibn.male`, `ibn.edu_lvl` and `ibn.age_cat` are not variables, which is the cause of your error. You could calculate summary statistics by the levels of a variable, but `estpost summarize` doesn't support a `by()` option. `estpost tabstat` does, so you could use this instead.